# How to go to a specific place in page by code?[Windows Phone][Silverlight] 

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In Silverlight for Windows phone, I need to go to a specific place in a page by code (hopefully with animation). The requirement is a bit like navigate to a specific anchor in HTML using url such as http://url#anchorname. However, I don't know how to do it in Windows Phone. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "go"? You could try setting the focus on a control calling control.Focus(). If you want to just scroll a ScrollViewer or a ListBox to display a control that is inside of it - WPF had a BringIntoView() method that some people ported to Silverlight, eg. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotjosh/archive/2009/11/05/bringintoview-extension-method-for-silverlight-with-behavior.aspx).

If you want animation - you will need to add an attached dependency property that will allow to run an animation updating the scroll offset using ScrollToVerticalOffset(). Then have the BringIntoView implementation - instead of just jumping to the offset using ScrollToVerticalOffset - run an animation that will update the attached dependency property and smoothly animate calling ScrollToVerticalOffset many times.

Comment: Thx for the prompt reply. I will try your approach. As for the meaning of "go", let me provide an example. Let's say a windows phone user scroll down to the bottom of a page. Then he/she would like to “go” back to the top of the page. I need to put a button on the buttom of the page to enable this.

Comment: If the scrolled content is simply a content in a ScrollViewer - you can call ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(). If you have a ListBox - you will need to use GetTemplateChild or VisualTreeHelper first to get access to the ScrollViewer that is part of the ListBox template.